# Programmatically added UI items order next to each other

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview

There is a UIScrollView and I'd like to programmatically put subviews in it. It's ok, but how can I lay automatically the subviews next to each other?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The view hierarchy in UIKit--like the view hierarchy in most UI frameworks--uses explicit layout.

Your comment asks about HTML-like floating; the box model stuff that HTML/CSS uses was designed to serve a very different goal (flowing document layout) than what UIKit is for, and so there's no real analogy in the framework.

UIViews *do* support automatic re-layout on resize/frame change of the parent view (you can say whether a subview should resize, how, and where it should be "pinned" to), through the autoresizing mask property, but I don't think that's what you're asking for.

You could, if you were inclined, build a set of methods, perhaps as a category on UIView, that let you add subviews that had their frame origins adjusted automatically based on existing subviews.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm going to make a wrapper to manage the subviews automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The position of the subviews is dictated by their `frame` property. So you need to set their frames such that they line up next to each other.

If they are all the same size you can do with some simple math and `CGRectMake()`.  If they will have different sizes, you can use `CGRectDivide()` to break a large rect into smaller rects.  `CGRectInset()` is also useful, in case you want some padding between them.

Comment: Thanks the answer! I know the frame-way but is there any solution to automate it? Like in HTML div float:left.

Comment: @haxpanel, you should have said in the question that you already know about frame and looking for something automated process.